How do I send keyboard input to a DirectX9 game using SendInput in Delphi?
I found this answer saying the following:

You can use the unmanaged SendInput function for this. It posts the input on a level lower then DirectInput. It is very important to know what keycodes to send. These can vary between games. If Windows Virtual keycodes don't work for a game, you can try sending DIKEYBOARD constants (like DIKEYBOARD_A etc.) and if it still doesn't work keep trying. Half Life or Counter Strike, for instance, expect ASCII codes as keycodes (it took me a while to figure this out)

This means using the SendInput() function in Delphi should work for my use case.

I found these C++ code examples:
Pressing the keyboard button state down:
static void SetInputDX(WORD input_code_set)
{
  INPUT inp[1];
  memset(inp,0,sizeof(INPUT));
  inp[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inp[0].ki.wScan = input_code_set;
  SendInput(1, inp, sizeof(INPUT));
}

Pressing the keyboard button state up:
static void ReleaseInputDX(WORD input_code_release)
{
  INPUT inp[1];
  memset(inp,0,sizeof(INPUT));
  inp[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inp[0].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  inp[0].ki.wScan = input_code_release;
  SendInput(1, inp, sizeof(INPUT));
}


I've gone ahead and converted them to Delphi as best as I can:
Pressing the keyboard button state down:
procedure SetInputDX(input_code_set: Word);
begin
  var inp: array[0..0] of TInput;
  FillChar(inp, SizeOf(inp), 0);
  inp[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inp[0].ki.wScan := input_code_set;
  SendInput(1, inp[0], SizeOf(TInput));
end;

Pressing the keyboard button state up:
procedure ReleaseInputDX(input_code_release: Word);
begin
  var inp: array[0..0] of TInput;
  FillChar(inp, SizeOf(inp), 0);
  inp[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inp[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  inp[0].ki.wScan := input_code_release;
  SendInput(1, inp[0], SizeOf(TInput));
end;

Does my Delphi conversion look correct?

How do I now send keyboard input to them since I don't have the DIKEYBOARD constants (like DIKEYBOARD_A, etc) available to me in Delphi, or do I?
I basically want to press = and INS within the game from my Delphi application.

Edit:
I've tried using ki.wVk instead of ki.wScan, and then passing the VK_INSERT constant to the functions as suggested by Remy, but that doesn't work.
I've also tried to make sure the window is active and in the foreground as suggested by IInspectable and AmigoJack using the procedures from this answer, but that's not helping or working either for me. The game still doesn't get the keypresses it seems.
This is how I'm calling the functions:
MakeWindowActive('PORTAL 2 - Direct3D 9');
SetInputDX(VK_INSERT);
ReleaseInputDX(VK_INSERT);

It seems like MakeWindowActive is working as the game's window is brought to the front and made active and focused, but it doesn't seem like the VK_INSERT is sent to the game.

I also found AttachThreadInput which seems interesting, but I don't know yet if it's useful for me or not.

Games in general don't observe synthesized input. They usually operate at a lower level (DirectInput/XInput/Raw Input). You should probably verify with a C++ application whether this approach works altogether. Also, you cannot SendInput() to a specific window: It will always go to the foreground window.

...because input can always only go to an active window and at max only one window can be active.

@IInspectable SendInput posts to the same input queue that physical hardware posts to, which Raw Input reads from. But synthesized input is easy to identify, so games can ignore it if they want to

@ShaunRoselt the DIKEYBOARD_ constants are part of the DirectInput API, you can't use them with SendInput(). You can use only physical scan codes, virtual key codes, or Unicode characters. For example, you can use VK_INSERT for the INS key

First of all you should have shared information about which game you are trying to control using your application. As already said in comments there are many different ways games can monitor for user input. So while one way might work for certain games it may not work for other games.

@SilverWarior For Source-based games. Same as what is in the quoted text from my question. Although the specific Source games I'm currently trying it on is using DirectX 9 .

@RemyLebeau Doing SetInputDX(VK_INSERT); ReleaseInputDX(VK_INSERT); doesn't seem to be working.

@ShaunRoselt That is because you are sending the virtual key code in the ki.wScan (scan code) field instead of the ki.wVk (virtual key code) field.  Read the SendInput documentation and in particular KEYBDINPUT. You might also read Keyboard Input Overview to understand the difference between the two values

@RemyLebeau I have tried with ki.wVk as well. Still doesn't work.

@ShaunRoselt Then, it's possible the game in question simply doesn't recognize/allow synthesized input, as described earlier. Did you TEST the game with existing input simulators before trying to write your own?

@RemyLebeau I've tested it with "AutoHotKey" and "Logitech G HUB" and both of them are able to send keyboard inputs to the game. What I've done with both of the software is, every time I click my mouse left button, then it presses the "INSERT" key and that worked without any issues.

@ShaunRoselt AutoHotKey uses SendInput(). and since AHK is open-source, you can see exactly how it does that: https://github.com/AutoHotkey

To make a window the foreground window requires a call to SetForegroundWindow. Keep in mind that Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you.

"I also found AttachThreadInput which seems interesting, but I don't know yet if it's useful for me or not." - It isn't.

@ShaunRoselt When you say "Source games" do you mean games that are made with Valve's Source Game Engine?

@SilverWarior Yes

Looking at iinputsystem.h from Source Game Engine I get impression that Source Game Engine relies on retrieving user input by pooling GetKeyboardState. So using SendInput is the right approach. ...

... Do note that SendInput can be blocked by [UIPI]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation) and there is no way for you to detecting this since neither GetLastError nor return value of the SendInput function will indicate that.

Speaking of SendInput you may want to check SendInputHelper to make your life using SendInput a bit easier.
